# OpenCV GPU FaceDetector Example crashing on random frames

Tags: opencv, gpu

I'm trying out the Haarcascade based FaceDetection using the GPU module in OpenCV 2.3.1.

My code is compiling and sometimes it shows the initial frame with one or more ROI-rectangles drawn onto the output frame to highlight detected objects.

But after the 2nd or 3rd repeated call of this detector method it just crashes. The compiler says SIGABRT. Any suggestions on this?

Here's the code:

```
cv::Mat ProcessorWidget::detectGPU(Mat &img) {

    cv::gpu::CascadeClassifier_GPU cascade_gpu(QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this).toStdString());

    img.copyTo(image_cpu);
    gpu::GpuMat image_gpu(image_cpu);

    gpu::GpuMat objbuf;
    int detections_number = cascade_gpu.detectMultiScale( image_gpu,
              objbuf, 1.2);

    Mat obj_host;
    // download only detected number of rectangles
    objbuf.colRange(0, detections_number).download(obj_host);

    Rect* faces = obj_host.ptr<Rect>();
    for(int i = 0; i < detections_number; ++i)
       cv::rectangle(image_cpu, faces[i], Scalar(255));
    return image_cpu;
}
```

Another point is that some of the Haarcascade Classifiers coming with OpenCV will always crash my application when i use them. But some other classifiers always work on the first frame and then crash a few frames later.

BTW I initialize the classifier from within this method just for testing purposes. Inititalizing it just once when constructing the ProcessorObject didn't help either ...

Could the classifier-XML's be incompatible somehow?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

directly from the docs:

Only the old haar classifier (trained by the haar training application) and NVIDIA’s nvbin are supported.

Comment: My program is still crashing. I am using cascadeclassifier provided with OpenCV from 2010